# Celery+SQS don't receive messages

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to make a queue system using celery+sqs.

Still in my local environment with localstack I'm not able to receive messages in worker. It just doesn't show anything. There is a question some time ago, but I'm ok in their config.

I'm using all other SQS/SNS activities from other function, but isn't working from celery.

My current setup is like this:
Docker config:

```
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs,sns
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
      - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
    networks:
      - platform_default
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

And the celery instantiation is down, used a get_queue directly to be sure of its link.

```
    return Celery(
        "server",
        task_default_queue=config.sqs_celery.queue_name,
        broker=f"sqs://",
        broker_url=f"sqs://{config.sqs_celery.aws_access_key_id}:{config.sqs_celery.aws_secret_access_key}@{config.sqs_celery.broker_site_port}",
       # in my case: sqs://localstack:localstack@localhost:4566
        broker_transport_options={
            'region': config.sqs_celery.region,
            "predefined_queues": {
                config.sqs_celery.queue_name: {
                    "url": get_queue_url(config.sqs_celery.queue_name), 
                    # in my case: http://localstack:4566/000000000000/tasks 
                    'region': config.sqs_celery.region,
             }
            }
        }
)
```

Please maybe you have some ideas to start, because I lost half of the day trying to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
The queue url can't be solved, you have to check everything. I set it to "localhost" and it worked.